# Percentage and Money Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A client asks about a home mortgage for a property that is valued at $500,000. They explain that they need a 65% loan and can pay the remainder in cash as a down payment. How much is their down payment?

i) $175,000

ii) $275,000

iii) $325, 000

iv) $350,000

I know this might seem like a simple question, but I need to make sure I solve this example correctly before I start doing real questions. Can someone help me?

My work:

($500,000)(0.65) $= $325,000$

Then

$500,000 - $325,000 = $175,000

Answer is:

$175,000

Answer (score 1):

Your work seems correct. Find the part of the total that the loan is covering and subtract that from the total to find what remains to be paid (as a down payment).

Comment: So $175,000 is the answer? If so, thank you! I was not too sure what the down payment meant. I suppose it was another way of saying what is the final answer.